# Moving towards a point when said point is within a radius

Tags: python, geometry

Just as a disclaimer, I am new to Python.

(this is in graphics.py)

I have two points on a plane. One point "a" is the dot with a circle around it. Currently they look something akin to this:

[image]

Assume that point "a" is moving on a trajectory that will cause the circle to touch the other point.
My goal is to have point "a" begin moving towards the other point once the other point is within the bounds of the circle surrounding point "a" kinda like this situation:

[image]

It should also be noted that point "a" is the only point that is supposedly moving.

Ultimately, I want the points to touch.

Is there a way for me to do this? One possible solution I can currently think of is to have point "a" move to the (x,y) coordinates on which the other point lies, but that would mean that point "a" isn't moving to the other point due to the circle coming in contact with the other point.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: how are you representing point `a`'s movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's some pseudo code

```
if (a.x-b.x)**2 + (a.y-b.y)**2 <= a.radius**2:
   vec_a_b = b-a  # or you can do this component wise  
   a.velocity = normalized(vec_a_b)*a.velocity.magnitude
```

this assumes point `a` has a velocity vector, which encodes the direction it's currently headed in and its speed.
now you can use the velocity to move `a`:

```
a.x += a.velocity.x
a.y += a.velocity.y
```

Comment: Could you explain what `normalize(vector_a_b)*a.speed` does here?

Comment: `normalized()` gives a new vector with same direction and magnitude of 1, if you already have the direction (as a unit vector) you can just use it

Comment: `normalized(vec_a_b)*a.speed` is making point `a` move with its current speed in a new direction pointing toward point `b`

Comment: That makes more sense! On another note, in `vector_a_b = b - a` the `__sub__` operator wouldn't work because `a` and `b` are points, correct?

Comment: that's why i said it's pseudo code, it can be implemented many different ways. easiest option is to use some sort of a vector library. or just make a few helper functions to do the subtraction and whatnot for you

Comment: really dumb question, how would I create `x` and `y` components for `(a.x-b.x)**2 + (a.y-b.y)**2 <= a.radius**2:`?

Comment: look up Python OOP